# Problem with handling event of input field change by mask of jquery.maskedinput.js library

Tags: javascript, jquery, maskedinput

There is a field for entering a phone number.
When the mask number entry is completed, the submit button becomes active.
The code implementing this functionality is given below (it works). The code is implemented on jquery.maskedinput.js:

```
$('.mask-phone').mask('+1 (999) 999-99-99', {
    completed: function() {
        $('button').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('button').css({
            'background': 'red',
            'color': '#fff'
        });
    }

});
```

A task: If the user has deleted, for example, the last digit of the phone, the button should become inactive again.

Comment: I think [this plugin](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput#masked-input-plugin-for-jquery) is old and not being maintained by the author, I would recommend to use [inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) instead

Comment: This partially solved the problem. For the case of a full field cleaning: `$('#phone').inputmask("+7 (999) 999-99-99", {
        "oncomplete": function() {
            $('button').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('button').css({
                'background': 'red',
                'color': '#fff'
            });
        },
        "oncleared": function() {
            alert('inputmask cleared');
            $('button').attr('disabled');
        }
    });` But it does not work if you remove one character without changing focus.